# ASP.NET MVC not submitting in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$('#btn').submit(function () {
    $('#btn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    setTimeout('enableButton()', 500);
    return true;
});

function enableButton() {     
    $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

How can I submit the form in Internet Explorer?

Comment: try using $("#myform").submit(function(){});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$('#aspnetForm').submit(function() {
                $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            });

where **aspnetForm** is the name of the form